# Does the half filled water bottle pressure increase as more water from water evaporate into that empty space until that space become 100% humid?

Tags: thermodynamics, evaporation

When we kept a half empty bottle and half filled with water, and the air in bottle is not fully saturated of water vapor.
So we know that bottle from water will evaporate until the space in bottle is saturated and maintain an equilibrium.

So my doubt is
**Does the pressure inside bottle increase or not?** As more water  from bottle evaporate into that half space to make it completely saturated!

Comment: Probably would help to read about "partial pressures"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_pressure  as a starting point.

Comment: Sir , I understand it well enough upto my knowledge , but how does this  help me to understand that if water vapor reach to 100% humid in that space and maintainan equilibrium, that will pressure increase  in it or not? 

Answer (score 3):

There are two sources of pressure inside the half filled bottle: pressure from the air that the bottle contains and pressure from the water vapor that the bottle contains.  Water has a vapor pressure that depends only on temperature. Given enough time, water in the bottle will evaporate until the partial pressure of the water vapor inside the bottle equals the vapor pressure of water corresponding to the temperature of that water.  While the effect is small at ambient temperatures (e.g., anywhere close to 25 deg C), the water vapor will indeed add to the pressure inside the bottle.  For more information on how to calculate the vapor pressure of water, start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine_equation).

Comment: So pressure increase no? But not much! Does partial pressure of air in bottle decrease , I think so no??!!

Comment: @SureshChandraPal, yes, there is a pressure increase.  Also, the partial pressure of the air in the bottle follows the ideal gas law.  If the temperature remains constant, the partial pressure of air in the bottle remains constant.